# Simple-direct-injective modules

Tags: modules

A right $R$-module $M$ is called a **simple-direct-injective** module if it satisfies any of the following equivalent conditions:

1. For any simple submodules $A,B$ of $M$ with $A \cong B \subseteq^{\oplus} M$, $A \subseteq^{\oplus} M$.
2. For any simple submodules $A,B$ of $M$ with $A \cap B=0$, $A \oplus B \subseteq^{\oplus} M$.
3. If $M=A\oplus B$ with $A$ simple and $f:A \to B$ an $R$-homomorphism, then $\operatorname{Im}f \subseteq^{\oplus} B$.

It's also known that if $\lbrace X_1,\dotsc, X_n \rbrace$ is a finite set of simple summands of a simple-direct-injective module $M$, then $\sum_{k=1}^n X_k \subseteq^{\oplus} M$.

I need to prove that the sum of all simple summands of a simple-direct-injective module $M$ is fully invariant in $M$.

I proved it in the case when $M$ has only one simple summand.

**Proof.** First, we consider the case in which $M$ has only one simple summand $S$. Write $M=S \oplus L$ for some submodule $L\subseteq M$. Let $f\in \operatorname{End}(M)$ be arbitrary. Let $g:=\pi f:S \to L$, where $\pi:M \to L$ is the canonical projection. Suppose that $g\neq 0$. Therefore, $g:S \to L$ is a monomorphism. Consequently, $g(S) \cong S \subseteq^{\oplus} M$. Since $M$ is simple-direct-injective, then $g(S)$ is a simple summand of $M$ that is distinct from $S$, contradicting the hypothesis that $M$ has only one simple summand. Thus, we must have $g=0$ which implies that $f(S) \subseteq S$. Hence, $S$ is fully invariant in $M$.

How can I prove the general case?